# Filtering results of Python LDAP query

Tags: python, regex, ldap

I am trying to do some processing of results of LDAP query using Python and ldap module. In the returned list of LDAP objects (actually list of lists where some elements are dictionariest) I have 'cn' attributes with values like this:
`tag-<username>`,
`krh-<username>`,
`tag-<username>-ab`,
`tag-<username>-ac`,
`tag-<username>-ad`,
`rrt-<username>`.

I would like to use just those with the exact pattern `tag-<username>` (starting with `tag-` and without `-ab`, `-ac`, or `-ad` at the end).

What would be the easiest way to do it? I assume matching with regular expressions but what would be the right regex to use in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to filter the results : `tag-([^-]+)$`

The parentheses allows to capture the matched username but you don't necessarily need it.

- `tag-` matches the characters `tag-` literally (case sensitive).
- Capturing group `([^-]+)`.

  - `[^-]+` matches a single character not present in the list below  :

    - `-` matches the character `-` literally (case sensitive).
    - `+` quantifier : matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any).

For example, the string `tag-usertest` gives a full match, capturing group `usertest`, and strings like `tag-usertest-<any>` won't match.

You can run some test here : https://regex101.com/r/D4a7I7/1/tests